# Is there a way to check if a stream/subject has an error?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I'm creating a Flutter form using BehaviorSubjects and I have some fields that are required, so I need to check them before continuing to the next form step. However, some of them also have some extra requirements to be considered OK, like the e-mail field. I'm using a stream transformer (.fromHandlers) in these fields to add an error if they don't match the requirements. I thought that there were some "hasError" method to check the BehaviorSubject, but there isn't.

I'm currently handling this by having a submit button that, when tapped, verify the forms with some code that look like the Handlers methods I have on the transformer, but I think it doesn't look like a good solution :(

Here are some of my code:

How I'm creating my subjects:

```dart
  Observable<String> get email => _email.stream.transform(validateEmail);
```

The form's submit function:

```dart
bool submitSignUp() {
    bool ok = true;

    if (getEmail == null || !validEmail(getEmail)) {
      ok = false;
      _email.addError("* Digite um email válido");
    }

    if (getfullName == null || getfullName.length < 3) {
      ok = false;
      _fullName.addError("* Digite um nome válido");
    }

    if (getPassword == null || getPassword.length < 6) {
      ok = false;
      _password.addError("* A senha deve conter pelo menos 6 caracteres.");
    }

    if (getPhoneNumber == null || getPhoneNumber.length < 11) {
      ok = false;
      _phoneNumber.addError("* Digite um número de telefone válido");
    }

    return ok;
  }
```

And my validators look like this:

```dart
final validateEmail = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (email, sink) {
      RegExp emailRegExp = RegExp(
          r'^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$');
      if (email.isEmpty) {
        sink.addError("* Campo obrigatório");
      } else if (!emailRegExp.hasMatch(email)) {
        sink.addError("* Digite um email válido");
      } else {
        sink.add(email);
      }
    },
  );
```

If there was the "hasError" method, I could create a list containg all my BehaviorSubjects and do a for loop checking for errors, just returning if the form is completed or not at the end. I don't know what's the best way to deal with this situation. Can you guys help me?

Comment: http://dartdoc.takyam.com/docs/tutorials/streams/#error-handling

Comment: @pskink thanks for the link, it helped me to find a solution :)

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: If you want to use streams for each field and the form you can check https://github.com/GiancarloCode/form_bloc/tree/master/packages/flutter_form_bloc

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is not really the answer for the question, but more a workaround that I did...

I made a list containing booleans for every observable I have, and using the onData and onError I change the values of the list, then when the button is pressed I check if all values are true. I still don't know if it is the best solution, but it's definitely better than the old one.

Here is the code:

```dart
SignupOrEditBloc() {
    List<Observable> observables = [
      displayName,
      fullName,
      email,
      cpf,
      rg,
      birthday,
      cep,
      address,
      addressNumber,
      neighborhood,
      state,
      city,
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < observables.length; i++) {
      boolList.add(false);
      observables[i]
          .listen((_) => boolList[i] = true)
          .onError((_) => boolList[i] = false);
    }
  }
```

and the submit function:

```dart
bool submitSignup() {
    bool ok = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < boolList.length; i++) {
      ok = ok && boolList[i];
    }

    for (BehaviorSubject subject in subjects()) {
      if (subject.value == null || subject.value == "") {
        subject.addError("* Campo obrigatório");
      }
    }

    return ok;
  }
```